# Responsive Layout with multiple divs inside divs

Tags: android, html, css

I've been trying to make a somewhat responsive layout for my website. But I'm late on the project and I've started it without one, which means my basic template has big flaws. 
I'd like to know how can I make such template? I believe it would be really simple to make a template like this (in the picture) but I don't really know how as the divs seem to be moving as they wish, not as I command.

What I want from that picture is exactly what's written there. As the browser view port is smaller the divs should behave in the way I've exemplified in the image.

If anyway could point me out how to make such things I'd appreciate :)

Here is the link to the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzHHO.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of PocketGrid, a micro CSS grid for responsive layouts.

As Luca suggested, you can use PocketGrid to make your layout.

I did a JSFiddle for you : http://jsfiddle.net/arleray/5Mvph/

The HTML is really simple:

```
<div id="LAYOUT" class="block-group">
    <div id="HEADER" class="block">
        <div class="box">HEADER</div>
    </div>
    <div id="WORK_AREA" class="block-group">
        <div id="LEFT_BAR" class="block">
            <div class="box">LEFT_BAR</div>
        </div>
        <div id="CONTENT" class="block">
            <div class="box">CONTENT</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="TOOLBOX" class="block-group">
        <div class="TOOLBOX_ITEM block">
            <div class="box">TOOLBOX ITEM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="TOOLBOX_ITEM block">
            <div class="box">TOOLBOX ITEM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="TOOLBOX_ITEM block">
            <div class="box">TOOLBOX ITEM</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For your CSS, I suggest you to use the "**mobile-first**" strategy:

1 - Start with the "mobile" version (the smallest):

```
#LAYOUT { min-width: 800px; }
#HEADER { height: 30px; }
#WORK_AREA { width: 100%; }
#LEFT_BAR { width: 300px; }
#CONTENT {
    overflow: hidden; /* Trick to fill the remaining space */
    float: none;
    width: auto;
}
#TOOLBOX {
    min-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

2 - Then add media queries for larger versions (> 1100px) to only add changes from the mobile version:

```
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
    #WORK_AREA { width: calc(100% - 300px); }
    #TOOLBOX { width: 300px; }
}
```

For the fluid CONTENT width, I used the "`overflow:hidden`" trick to make it fill the remaining space of the WORK_AREA, after the LEFT_BAR.
Nevertheless, to make the WORK_AREA fluid with the fixed toolbar on the right, I could not use "overflow:hidden" (because it fills the remaining space on the right).
So I had to use the `calc()` function to compute the WORK_AREA width because of the right fixed-width toolbox.

**Note**: The calc() function is only compatible with Android 4.4+ (http://caniuse.com/calc) but it's the only mean (with pure CSS) to have a fluid WORK_AREA on the left of the right sidebar, because the TOOLBOX is declared after the WORK_AREA.
You may try using this calc() polyfill (in JS): https://github.com/CJKay/PolyCalc

To use the "overflow:hidden" trick instead of the calc() function, you should place your toolbox BEFORE the WORK_AREA, like in this other JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arleray/5Mvph/11/

For more information about **PocketGrid**, you can see many examples here: http://arnaudleray.github.io/pocketgrid/docs/

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are a god. I worship you!
I mean it! Thanks!

Is there like anyway to make the content also go down, the same way the tool box's go down?

Answer (score 1):

You can use media query in css refer [media queries here](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) or you can use framework like [Bootstrap](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/). This will help you to control divs based on devices sizes.

Comment: but how do I get the template that I want with that?

Comment: Use Grid system from bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid It will help you to make coloumn like your layout.

Answer (score 1):

try bootstrap.It will make your life easy link is [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html).hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you another very very simple and minimalistic Grid system: [PocketGrid](http://arnaudleray.github.io/pocketgrid/). Only 1 KB minified. Loot at demos and description. ;-)